# Regex - locate nth position from EOL

Tags: regex, linux, bash, perl

I have a directory with filenames in which the dot is missing, that marks the beginning of the file extension:

```
filename1jpg 
filename2JPG 
filename3MPG
```

I now want to add a `.` before the third position from the end of the line, so that the filename will be renamed to:

```
filename1.jpg 
filename2.JPG
filename3.MPG
```

Most convenient it might be with `rename` on the shell, but I can't imagine a regex for that. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a perl one-liner.

```
perl -e 'rename $_, s/\.?(...)$/.$1/r for <*>'
```

Or using the shell rename:

```
rename 's/\.?(...)$/.$1/' *
```

Comment: that worked, the rename command not. So i accept your answer, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You could try the below rename command on the directory where the files are located.

```
rename 's/(...)$/.$1/' *
```

`$` means end of a line anchor. And `()` called capturing groups which are used to capture the characters. So `(...)$` this capturing group would capture the last three characters and save it into group index 1. Then  the matched substring(*last three characters*) was replaced by a dot plus the characters inside group index 1 (*last three characters*).

Comment: a got it. you match the last 3 characters from EOL, have it saved in $1 and then replace it by '.' + $1

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex like this:

```
(.*)(...)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/uR5dP2/1)**

[image]

Using substitution you can have this:

[image]

The idea is to capture the beginning of the string and the last 3 characters, so using capturing group content you will concat a dot like `\1`.`\2`

Answer (score 1):

Find `(?<=[^.])(?=[^.]{3}$)`
Replace `.`

Answer (score 1):

Here's alternative way:

```
awk '{print $1, $1}' | awk '{$2=gensub(/...$/,".\\0","",$2); print}' | xargs -n2 echo mv
```

It can be executed by droping `echo`.